# Looking for a design pattern for populating classes without a database

Tags: java, c#, oop, design-patterns

I'm looking for design pattern to help with a particular problem related to class instantiation

Lets say I have a class called CarModel and it has properties like:

```
CarModel
{
  string MakeName
  string ModelName
  int NumberOfDoors
  int NumberOfLiters
  string StereoMake
  bool HasAC
  List<Color> ColorOptions
  ...etc
}
```

And lets say my app will instantiate this class from multiple locations in code for different car models (like 2015 Toyota Camry LE, 2015 Toyota Corolla SE, 2013 Ford Mustang GT, etc).

These are not singletons, however every time it's instantiated for 2015 Toyota Camry LE, the base properties will always be the same (because those are the properties of a 2015 Toyota Camry LE).  All properties will get filled for all car models (so this isn't a case for builder).

Finally, suppose these properties cannot be obtained from a database or config file (suppose platform doesn't support it).

What I don't want to happen is, I don't want every place in code where carModel gets instantiated, to have to pass in these properties as parameters to the constructor.  The caller should not have to know them, plus it can lead to errors and maintenance issues.

What I do want to happen is, I want the caller to just specify what car model it wants, and the class should be populated.  Typically such a use case I would do with a database backend, but again, that's not an option here.

What I'm thinking right now is, that I'll pass in an enum value to the constructor, and the class will initialize itself based on that.  So:

```
public CarModel(CarModelTypes cmt)
{
  if(cmt == CarModelTypes.2015_Toyota_Camry_LE)
  {
  MakeName = "Toyota";
  ModelName = "Camry";
  NumberOfDoors = 4;
  etc...
  }
  else if(cmt == CarModelTypes.2013_Ford_Mustang_GT)
  {
  MakeName = "Ford";
  ModelName = "Mustang";
  NumberOfDoors = 2;
  etc
  }
  else if(etc...
}
```

I'd put it into a seperate function, but you get the idea.  Not sure I like that though.  Feels ugly.  Then I thought I could create a class for each car model type that inherits from CarModel and they can instantiate themselves, so:

```
public class Car2015ToyotaCamryLE : CarModel
{
  string MakeName = "Toyota";
  string ModelName = "Camry";
  int NumberOfDoors = 4
  etc

  public Car2015ToyotaCamryLE()
  {
  }
}
```

But seems like what I'm really doing here is creating instances of classes as classes themselves, which doesn't feel right at all.  Plus number of classes could grow.  Even if we kept it to 20 models, that's still 20 extra classes in the project.

So, that's why I'm here.  Anyone have any good ideas of a clean way to handle this or anyone know of a design pattern specifically designed for this?  Otherwise I'll probably just go with the first option.

Thanks

Comment: Building cars seems like the perfect job for a [car factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: You need to store data in a data storage structure.  It's that simple.  Creating classes to store data is a TERRIBLE idea since it makes the project completely unmanageable.  What happens when 2016 models release?  If you absolutely cannot store data in a database, what about storing it in a nice, lean, json structure?

Comment: What are you planning to do with the cars? Is there a chance that you have multiple instances of the same car model? Are you going to be doing different things depending on the model? Are you sure you can not save the data in any place?

Comment: @DavidL I agree that's the proper way.  Beyond the scope of this question, there were reasons why it was an issue and why we weren't going with that approach.  But if the benefits outweigh the downsides, it might just need to happen.  Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: @Dzyann Yes there can be multiple instances of the same car model.  The storage of the data is last resort, but it seems most here agree that best option is to store, and secondary option is factory.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking past the apparent oddity of your requirements, this is a clear case of the [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Your example in the middle about halfway down is the exact anti-pattern to the factory pattern. If you look at the article I linked up above, you will see the following. This appears to achieve your given requirements, and it is perfectly acceptable to store this information in class files, though it makes it more difficult to change them out later (not sure it would be necessary in this example, just saying).

```
public interface ICar
{
    string GetMake();
    string GetModel();
}

public class ToyotaCamry : ICar
{
    #region ICar Members

    public string GetMake()
    {
        return "Toyota";
    }

    public string GetModel()
    {
        return "Camry";
    }

    #endregion
}

public class FordMustang : ICar
{
    #region ICar Members

    public string GetMake()
    {
        return "Ford";
    }

    public string GetModel()
    {
        return "Mustang";
    }
    #endregion
}

public enum CarType
{
    FordMustang,
    ToyotaCamry
}

/// <summary>
/// Implementation of Factory - Used to create objects
/// </summary>
public class Factory
{
    public ICar GetCar(CarType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case CarType.FordMustang :
                return new FordMustang();
            case CarType.ToyotaCamry:
                return new ToyotaCamry();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, I guess you're right.  (lol at the car factory comment above).  I didn't like this for 2 reasons: 1) Number of classes in app could be large as a result (although for my use case it'll still be just 20).  2) Felt like these were instances of classes that were instead becoming a class themselves.  i.e. when I think Factory pattern, I think more generic types, where as these are more specific, but it seems it's acceptable to get more specific as well.  Thanks

Comment: Well, you have to keep in mind is this is one reason they developed databases. Class differentiation really only makes sense if you absolutely need it for program functionality. The trend nowadays is to use anonymous/dynamic class objects (e.g. JSON) and give up type safety.